# Align data columns in LibreOffice Calc according to numbers in another column

Tags: libreoffice, sorting, libreoffice-calc

I have three columns:

- Column A contains a count from 1 to 100, representing different sample stations.  The numbers are in sequence.
- Column B is independent of column A.  It contains selected numbers from column A (values between 1 to 100) but not all of them because I get a list with data from only some of the stations each time.  Column B is sequenced in increasing order, but shorter than column A because it is missing some stations, and there are no blank cells to keep the column B entries aligned with the column A entries.
- Column C contains data associated with column B, for example a temperature reading at the sampling station or any other information.

Now I would like to avoid copying all information manually from Column C to where it belongs aligned with Column A. I want to align the column B and C values with the station list in column A, inserting empty spaces in columns B and C as necessary. Afterwards column B can be eliminated.

As an example:

```
ColA ColB ColC
  1    1    a
  2    2    d
  3    4    r
  4    6    e
  5    7    x
  6    9    r
  7    10   e
  8    11   f
  9    13   e
  10   15   e 
 ...,...,...
```

Should afterwards look like this ...

```
ColA ColB ColC
  1    1    a
  2    2    d
  3
  4    4    r
  5
  6    6    e
  7    7    x
  8
  9    9    r
  10   10   e
  11   11   f
  12
  13   13   e
  14
  15   15   e 
 ...,...,...
```

Comment: Do you have to sort the existing data, or would you mind if the sorted data uses a formula to reference the unsorted data and the unsorted data remains on the sheet? ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trKOB.png))

Comment: Stockfisch, I did a little cleanup and what I hope is clarification.  I think your description and word choice might have been confusing, which led to raddevus's answer.  Your example shows the data all sequenced in ascending order, and from the process you describe, it sounds like you get the data sequenced in station order, just not a complete set. I think you were using the term "sort" to mean "align" (no real sorting needed, just adding spaces so the stations line up).  Please review and verify that the edit is all correct.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR version: Put original data in A3:B102, fill D3:D102 with numbers 1-100, paste `=IFNA(VLOOKUP($D3,$A$3:$B$102,2, FALSE), "")` in E3, then copy E3 to E4:E102.

---

Based on your description of what you want, I'd recommend separating the sorting from the original data and instead having a list of sampling stations and using a `VLOOKUP` to find the data for each one.

You need three things.

1. A place to paste your unsorted and/or incomplete list of data readings.

   - There should be enough space here for a full data set.
   - In this case, since you have 100 sampling stations and 1 reading per station, you'll want 100 rows and two columns.
   - For my example this will be the range **A3:B102**.
2. A list of sampling stations and a place to put their associated readings next to them.

   - This list should include all sampling stations in the order you want to see them.
   - Again, we're looking at 100 sampling stations, numbered 1-100 and we want them in numeric order. This means we need to fill one column with 1, 2, 3, etc. to 100, and the column next to it will contain a formula.
   - For my example the list of sampling stations will go in **D3:D102**, and the formula will be copied to all cells in **E3:E102**.
3. A formula that goes in the sorted data's "Reading" column that looks up the appropriate data in the unsorted data.

   - You should understand both absolute and relative references, as this formula uses both:

     - Most people are familiar with relative references like **D3**. These references get changed when they're copied from one cell to another.
       (e.g. If you put `=D3` in **E3**, then copy **E3** to **E4**, the new copy in **E4** will read `=D4`.)
     - Absolute references contain a `$` on the column and/or row to prevent it from changing when copied.
       (e.g. The column will never change when copying `=$D3` around, but the row will; likewise, with `=D$3`, the column will change, but the row will not; and finally `=$D$3` will always reference that cell, never changing when copied.)
   - The formula goes in the top row of sorted data readings, and should then be copied down to the next 99 cells below it.
   - The formula to look up the right data which goes in **E3** is `=VLOOKUP($D3,$A$3:$B$102,2, FALSE)`, but this places `#N/A` in the cells that reference non-existant data. If you want blank spaces instead of `#N/A` you'll want to put the `VLOOKUP` inside an `IFNA`.

---

The completed formula for this example is `=IFNA(VLOOKUP($D3,$A$3:$B$102,2, FALSE), "")` and this is what the results look like:
[image: Original Data, (blank column), Sorted Data]

Comment: @fixer1234: The method I used handles all entries fine, whether in or out of sequence. I chose to include several 'out of sequence' entries in order to show that this won't prevent it from working properly. Re: station 3, I generated the dataset pictured myself, I don't see why you're comparing it to the data in the question, as it's obviously very different. Re: 'the initial copy/paste', no you can't skip pasting the original data in, as that's how the data gets into the sheet to begin with.

Comment: @fixer1234: Also, reorganizing it as you suggest in order to then delete the original data is pointless and won't work, as the sorted data is only a reference, meaning that as soon as you delete the original data, it'll delete the sorted data too.

Comment: Brain out of coffee.  Yes, the results would disappear without copying (D'oh!), but B:C could be hidden, instead  :-).  On handling out-of-sequence values, that wasn't really a requirement, and it just seemed to make the solution appear more complicated and harder to follow, but there's nothing wrong with doing it.  I spotted your answer, which had a good approach, but hadn't received an upvote.  It seemed long and complicated, which might have scared off the OP.  Just a VLOOKUP in col D seemed a lot easier to explain.  (cont'd)

Answer (score 0):

1. Define a data range you want to sort (Menu/Data/Define ranges)
2. Set up sort options in Menu/Data/Sort,
3. select columns in the order you want (Sort Criteria tab)
4. mark properly if Range contains column labels.
5. mark "Copy sort to" an enter destination range (all columns are
   copied)

Comment: I cannot get it to work. I selected ColumnA and defined it as a data range according to which I want to sort data. I then select columnB and columnC and choose Sort, select options in the Sort Criteria Tab and mark 'Range contains column labels' and after mark 'Copy sort to', select ColumnA from the list (the second field is filled in automatically with data range of ColumnA) and choose Ok. The only thing that happens is that ColumnB and ColumnC replace ColumnA.

Comment: I think this does not do what I want. It just copies a sorted list to another place in a datasheet but does not consider sort the column according to data in another column.

Comment: This solution would require you to ignore Column A and sort columns B & C by column B, but it would not place the spaces you want where you have no data.